# Transform File Content

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following file:

```
Dj Assad;Laurell
Sweat
--
Steve Aoki;BTS
Waste it on me
--
Oliver Heldens;Shungudzo
Fire in my soul
--
```

I want to transform it so that:

```
Dj-Assad-Laurell-Sweat
--
Steve-Aoki-BTS-Waste-it-on-me
--
Oliver-Heldens-Shungudzo-Fire-in-my-soul
--
```

I have tried:

```
sed -e 's/;/ /g; s/ /-/g' file.txt
```

But it does not remove the newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ <file.txt tr '\n' '\0' | sed 's/\x0--\x0/\n--\n/g' | tr '\0; ' '-'
Dj-Assad-Laurell-Sweat
--
Steve-Aoki-BTS-Waste-it-on-me
--
Oliver-Heldens-Shungudzo-Fire-in-my-soul
--
```

- `<file.txt tr '\n' '\0'` convert all `\n` (newline) to `\0` (NULL) characters
- `| sed 's/\x0--\x0/\n--\n/g'` convert `\0--\0` to `\n--\n`
- `| tr '\0; ' '-'` convert remaining NULL, semicolon and space characters to `-`

Comment: `tr '\0; ' '-' ` this command It can be done with `sed` ?????

Comment: Yes you can: `sed 's/[\x0; ]/-/g'`

Comment: what does this mean `\x0` ??

Comment: It's the [hexadecimal ASCII escape sequence](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html) of the NULL character `\0`. You need to escape these in `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
sed -i -e 'N;N;s/\(;[a-zA-Z]*\)\n/\1-/g; s/[ ;]/-/g' foo
```

Edit: Added the semicolon conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
tr '\n' '-' <file | sed -e 's/[ ;]\+/-/g' -e 's/----/\n--\n/g'
```

First it will replace newlines with `-` and then sed will remove space and semicolon with `-` and finally line with `--` will be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of Awk options:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n--\n"; ORS=RS; FS="[ ;]|\n"; OFS="-"} {NF+=0} 1' file.txt
Dj-Assad-Laurell-Sweat
--
Steve-Aoki-BTS-Waste-it-on-me
--
Oliver-Heldens-Shungudzo-Fire-in-my-soul
--
```

or (GNU Awk specific):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\n--\n"; ORS=RS; FPAT="[[:alnum:]]+"; OFS="-"} {NF+=0} 1' file.txt
Dj-Assad-Laurell-Sweat
--
Steve-Aoki-BTS-Waste-it-on-me
--
Oliver-Heldens-Shungudzo-Fire-in-my-soul
--
```